# Bass model in DoCplex: how to assign variables in constraints

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, bass, docplex

I am trying to build an optimisation program based on Bass model (see below):

- Decision variables: p, m, q
- Problem: min RMSE
- Constraints:

  - Ft = (p + q(C(t-1)/m)(m - C(t-1))
  - Et = Ft - St

with C(t) being the cumulative sum of sales, St being the actual amount of sales, Ft being the predicted sales for period t and Et being the error term.

I cannot seem to figure out how to write constraints that assign such values to new variables (and not necessarily use comparative operators)...

For the moment, I created a Bass_F function doing the equation Ft above, and an rmse function computing the rmse. I also wrote the following code (my actual sales value are variable y and I have 4 records in it):

```
import docplex.mp.model as cpx
opt_model = cpx.Model(name="Bass")

opt_model.continuous_var(name = "p")
opt_model.continuous_var(name = "q")
opt_model.continuous_var(name = "m")

F = [None]*4
E = [None]*4
opt_model.add_constraint_(F[0] = p*m)
opt_model.add_constraint_(E[0] = F[0] - y[0])
for i in range(1,len(F)):
    opt_model.add_constraints_(F[i] = Bass_F(F[i-1], p, q, m))
    opt_model.add_constraints_(E[i] = F[i] - y[i])
```

Obviously this gives me an error, which is:

```
opt_model.add_constraint_(F[0] = p*m)                             ^
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "define" variables like you would define macros or similar. What you can do is this:

```
opt_model.add_constraint_(F[0] == p*m)
opt_model.add_constraint_(E[0] == F[0] - y[0])
for i in range(1,len(F)):
    opt_model.add_constraints_(F[i] == Bass_F(F[i-1], p, q, m))
    opt_model.add_constraints_(E[i] == F[i] - y[i])
```

This for example forces `F[0]` to be the same as `p * m`. The solver engine will substitute `F[0]` by `p * m` whenever necessary.

You can also create this sort of definition *outside* the model. That is, you can do this:

```
F = []
F.append(p * m)
```

After this, `F[0]` is an expression that you can use whenever you want to reference `p * m`. So your code could be written as (replace `M` with an appropriate limit)

```
F = [None] * M
E = [None] * M
F[0] = p * m
E[0] = F[0] - y[0]
for i in range(1, M):
    F[i] = Bass_F(F[i - 1], p, q, m)
    E[i] = F[i] - y[i]
```

With that you can use `F[i]` and `E[i]` as "shortcuts" for the respective expressions.

As far as I can see, there is an issue with your model, though. You define

```
Ft = (p + q(C(t-1)/m)(m - C(t-1))
```

This requires division by decision variable `m`. Dividing by decision variables is not supported. You multiply both sides by `m` to get rid of that. The resulting constraint may be non-convex, though. That is not supported either. You may have to linearize this constraint.

Comment: Thanks for the help!! And sorry for the delayed reply (somehow didn't get a notification).